# Как убрать декорацию функции?

Tags: c++

Есть библиотека с функцией которая возвращает контейнер. Примерно такая:

`std::set<std::string> function();`

Библиотеку нужно загружать динамически, значит чтобы найти эту функцию нужно убрать декорацию, как это сделать?
`extern "C"` использовать не получится, так как функция возвращает класс С++. Под Windows вроде можно использовать def файл, но как сделать такое под Linux?

Comment: Ну если уж до такой степени важно сделать на C - то возвращайте указатель `void*`, каковой в действительности является указателем на класс :)

Comment: это задача линкера. Если ваш компилятор поддерживает def файлы - пропишите соответствие.

Comment: Вот http://erfaren.narod.ru/Asm/Erfaren003.htm пример. Имена слева писать нужно такие как в obj файле. Справа как в dll. Например `_RtlCharToInteger@4= ntdll.RtlCharToInteger ` Укажите какой у вас компилятор. Тогда вам можно записать соответствие.

Comment: Для borland так `@function$qv = dllfile.function`

Comment: Вы не должны передавать ничего кроме plain old data через границы DLL. Используйте `extern "C"`

Comment: @Harry: Очень плохой совет. Если версия рантайма, с которой скомпилирован клиент DLL, другая, получите испорченную память.

Comment: У меня мало опыта с работы с dll, поэтому тоже задам вопрос присутствующим. А эту проблему нельзя решить при помощи out-параметра? `void function(std::set<std::string> &result)`

Comment: Да действительно, если перенести в out-параметр то можно  указать extern "C". Но все-таки хотелось бы через return.
По поводу plain old data. Если сборка MD, то я не вижу причин не передавать С++ классы за границы DLL

Comment: @Anton: Подумайте, в _какой именно_ heap вернётся память, которая выделена в основной программе при помощи `new`, когда DLL вызывает `delete`. Подумайте, что будет, если версия компилятора или рантайма, с которой собраны DLL и основная программа, различаются. Ужаснитесь.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, а какая разница? Декорирование будет для любой C++ функции; нельзя использовать C++ типы с extern C.

Comment: @VladD А кто мешает добавить вторую функцию `destroy`, например, и освобождать память в DLL?

Comment: @Harry: Тем, что стоковый оператор `delete` ей не пользуется. И тем, что когда у вас в программе есть указатель на данные, вы обычно не знаете, пришли они из DLL, или аллоцированы в главной программе.

Comment: @Harry: Я в своё время получил пару очень гадких крешей просто из-за того, что бинарный лэйаут одного класса был в дебаг-режиме не такой, как в релиз-режиме. DLL была скомпилирована в релизе, а приложение отлаживалось в дебаге.